# Separate Heap on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, heap-memory

In my project i have some plugins that get loaded at runtime via `LoadLibrary()`. From the book "Windows via C/C++" i know that objects created inside the DLL should be freed inside the DLL. `Object* CreateObj()` `void FreeObj(Object*)`. The reason is, there could be multiple linked C/C++ runtimes linked to the running process.

As i try to port my project to Linux, i used the same approach. But: Is that needed in Linux too? Is it possible that there are multiple heaps in a Linux process too?

Comment: Please note that even if not strictly necessary, it would still be considered good style to provide an explicity `FreeObj`. It makes it much easier to correctly use the library. Consider e.g. `free` vs `delete`...

Comment: I'm not sure that proposed duplicate is good candidate, since current question is about C++ runtime, not about standard C functions. Few C++ runtimes may use the same `malloc()` (and process heap) internally, but stay separated without  interchangeable `new/delete`. Marking this question as duplicate may result in misunderstanding for new readers IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If your `.so` are statically linked to C++ runtimes - you should free objects in the same module where they were allocated since `new/delete` is something more than `malloc()/free()` and need some extra info to work properly. Moreover you shouldn't even pass runtime-specific objects / pointers to objects (e.g. `std::string`) across `.so` modules, since modules in general may be linked against different and binary incompatible runtime implementations (e.g. you have some third-party prebuilt modules). And even if you use the same runtime implementation across all process - static linkage leads to creating of multiple instances of runtime's internal globals, that surely can cause mess.

So, IMHO, the best scenario - is to link all your modules against dynamic version of runtime. Or if you really want to use statically linked runtimes - you must expose pure C interface for each module to avoid mentioned above interferences.

P.S. Such behavior doesn't depend on actual system, it is related to anything that supports dynamically loadable modules.